# How can I hide google search field in safari?

Tags: safari

When customizing safari toolbar I can't get rid of google's search field right next to address bar. Is there any secret preference tweak to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Safari Omnibar**](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/#about).

[image: safari omnibar]

From the website:

> Features
>
> - Unified location bar with search bar
> - Search directly using location bar
> - Quickly switch engines using search engine keywords
> - Define new search engines

It works on Snow Leopard and Lion.

NB : it requires you to install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php). See the [FAQ](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/#faq) on the website.